# JsonConvert.PopulateObject not working with boolean value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json.net, jsonconvert

The below code wont map `false` over a `true` property using `JsonConvert.PopulateObject`.  The other properties work just fine. Am I doing something wrong?

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, request);
```

**JSON**

```
{ "EventId": 146282, "Name": "api division 9", "Order": 4, "Description": "test", "Active": false  }
```

**Account.cs**

```
[DataContract(Name = "Request", Namespace = "")]
    public class ApiCreateDivisionRequest : ApiAuthorizedRequest
    {
    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to put the `[DataContract(Name = "Request", Namespace = "")]` on it, replicates the bug. Looks like `EmitDefaultValue` needs to be true.  If you mark that as the answer Ill give it to you.

Comment: OK, once I added DataContract, [I was able to reproduce it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bZ9UX).

Comment: There seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2294) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmitDefaultValue` needs to be `true`